# Which microcontroller to select with A/D more than 24Mhz sample rate?

Tags: microcontroller

I am looking for a micro-controller a cheap one with dual A/D and at-least 8bit and sample rate more than or equal to 24Mhz.

Please someone provide me with name, number of such microcontroller or some online repository where i can search.

Comment: `online repository where i can search` .... google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample rates that high almost never come built in to a micro controller. An ADC with that sample rate is too expensive for the manufacturer to want to add it to their micro controller (and 90% of their customers will not make use of the high sample rate), and almost no micro controller on the market can do any sort of processing on 24MS/s. If you want such a thing, you’ll have to purchase an external one and connect it to something that can handle the sample rate, like an FPGA or **maybe** a high end DSP.